# Handle the default event in outlook 2010 VSTO

Tags: events, outlook, vsto

I have added the following code in the ribbon xml to handle the Meeting Accepted button.

```
<commands>
    <command idMso="AcceptInvitationNoResponse" onAction="HandleMeetingResponse"/>    
    <command idMso="AcceptInvitationEditResponse" onAction="HandleMeetingResponse"/>    
    <command idMso="AcceptInvitationSendResponse" onAction="HandleMeetingResponse"/>    
  </commands>
```

This is the corresponding event handler code.

```
public void HandleMeetingResponse(Office.IRibbonControl Control, bool Cancel)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Accepted Clicked");
            Cancel = false;
        }
```

Once the message box is shown, the default event of accepting the meeting and send the response is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Vijay,

The repurposed *onAction* callback should look like the following one:

```
C#: void OnAction(IRibbonControl control, ref bool CancelDefault)
VBA: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl, byRef CancelDefault)
C++: HRESULT OnAction([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [in,out] VARIANT _BOOL *fCancelDefault)
Visual Basic: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl, byRef CancelDefault)
```

It looks like you forgot to declare the **ref** keyword for the second parameter.

Comment: Even If I added the ref keyword, the default functionality is not executing.

Comment: Try to replace the MessageBox call with Debug.WriteLine statement. I belive the message box stops the default action from running.